# cannot import modules in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import

I have made this utility which i want to import in another file :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

/**
 * @todo Add documentation
 */
class SimplicateApi { 
    constructor(key,secret){
        this._key = key; 
        this._secret = secret; 
        this.baseUrl = 'https://simplicate.nl/api/v2'; 

        this.options = {
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'Authentication-Key' : this._key, 
                'Authentication-Secret' : this._secret
            }
        }
    }

    get(endpoint) {
        return fetch(`${this.baseUrl}${endpoint}`, this.options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json);
    }
}

export default SimplicateApi;
```

In another file im importing it like this :

```
import SimplicateApi from '../../utils/SimplicateApi';
```

The error I receive :

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import
>   {SimplicateApi} from '../../utils/SimplicateApi';
>                                                                        ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) PS C:\Users\klmaa\OneDrive\Bureaublad\dexhub\client\src\components\cmInf

I removed everything even the fetch and just exported the class like this :

```
// import fetch from 'node-fetch';

/**
 * @todo Add documentation
 */
class SimplicateApi { 

}

export default SimplicateApi;
```

Now im importing it like this :

```
import SimplicateApi from '../../utils/SimplicateApi';
```

The error still looks like :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import SimplicateApi from '../../utils/SimplicateApi';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)     
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)  
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
PS C:\Users\klmaa\OneDrive\Bureaublad\dexhub\client\src\components\cmInf
```

Comment: you mixing commonJs module and ES6 module both.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mixing both `CommonJs module` and [`ES6 module`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

In react, you should use ES6 module.
CommonJs module does not supported by React.You need to configure Babel for this.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // this wronng import syntax in React.
```

Changes should be

```
// if you are in react.
    import fetch from 'node-fetch'; // for react

//if you are in Node.
class SimplicateApi { 

}

module.exports = SimplicateApi;
```

Comment: I used import instead of require and i still get the same error

Comment: Please share the error and node-fetch file relevant code

Comment: So i updated my code and question , would you please take a look, the error still looks the exact same

Comment: Are you writing in nodejs or reactjs?

Comment: It's a react application , but a normal javascript function

Comment: Nodejs Version? How you created react app

Comment: i found the issue , i was running the file like "node file.js" i thought since i have react it'll work, but thats not the case.